# How to incorporate type checking in an abstract base class in Python

Tags: python, assert, abc

When I define a class, I like to include type checking (using `assert`) of the input variables. I am now defining a 'specialized' class `Rule` which inherits from an abstract base class (ABC) `BaseRule`, similar to the following:

```
import abc

class BaseRule(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def resources(self):
        pass


class Rule(BaseRule):
    def __init__(self, resources):
        assert all(isinstance(resource, Resource) for resource in resources)    # type checking
        self._resources = resources

    @property
    def resources(self):
        return self._resources


class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.domain = domain


if __name__ == "__main__":
    resources = [Resource("facebook.com")]
    rule = Rule(resources)
```

The `assert` statement in the `__init__` function of the `Rule` class ensures that the `resources` input is a list (or other iterable) of `Resource` objects. However, this would also be the case for other classes which inherit from `BaseRule`, so I would like to incorporate this assertion in the `abstractproperty` somehow. How might I go about this?

Comment: Also take a look at [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) for a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your base class have a non-abstract property that calls separate abstract getter and setter methods. The property can do the validation you want before calling the setter. Other code (such as the `__init__` method of a derived class) that wants to trigger the validation can do so by doing its assignment via the property:

```
class BaseRule(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @property
    def resources(self): # this property isn't abstract and shouldn't be overridden
        return self._get_resources()

    @resources.setter
    def resources(self, value):
        assert all(isinstance(resource, Resources) for resource in value)
        self._set_resources(value)

    @abstractmethod
    def _get_resources(self):   # these methods should be, instead
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _set_resources(self, value):
        pass

class Rule(BaseRule):
    def __init__(self, resources):
        self.resources = resources # assign via the property to get type-checking!

    def _get_resources(self):
        return self._resources

    def _set_resources(self, value):
        self._resources = value
```

You might even consider moving the `__init__` method from `Rule` into the `BaseRule` class, since it doesn't need any knowledge about `Rule`'s concrete implementation.

Comment: Might there be a typo in this snippet? Because I get `NameError: global name 'resource' is not defined` if I use it to replace my code.

Comment: Whoops, yes, I did have a typo (`for resources in value` should have been `for resource in value`), which I've now edited to fix. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

See this documentation on abc Type annotations with mypy-lang https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class_basics.html#abstract-base-classes-and-multiple-inheritance